# Activity with a webview shows old page when came back from other activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview

I have a complex workflow and I am facing some issues with it.

Step 1: I have MainActivity that has a fragment and the fragment has a webview which shows a mobile website. By default it opens the home page of the website. This `MainActivity` has singleTop launchmode.

Step 2: On clicking a link in home page it opens anotherActivity called `SearchActivity` which can handle these kind of url's. This activity has list of photos,  when clicked on any photo , it opens back MainActivity passing a new url.
I invoke the MainActivity like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);    
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.putExtra("url", newUrl);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Step 3: Now in MainActivity I go through the following urls
L1->L2->L3->L4

Step 4: Then I press back four times to go to the SearchActivity and then pressing back will take me back to MainActivity which launched SearchActivity in 
step 2.

Step 5. But here I see MainActivity instead of showing the home page, it is showing the page with L4.

When the SearchActivity created MainActivity, I have specifically instructed to create a new instance and pressing back buttons are handled and the finish is called where ever required.

What am I misssing/messing here.